# How can I display a large matrix without the word "Columns" appearing?

Tags: matlab, matrix, output, display

I want to display a large matrix, but I don't like the words "Columns x to y" to show. How can I do this?

Answer (score 12):

You can use the function [NUM2STR](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/num2str.html) to format a large 2-D matrix `A` into a character array and display that. For example:

```
>> A = magic(15);  %# This would likely break up columns when displayed
>> num2str(A)      %# This won't

ans =

122  139  156  173  190  207  224    1   18   35   52   69   86  103  120
138  155  172  189  206  223   15   17   34   51   68   85  102  119  121
154  171  188  205  222   14   16   33   50   67   84  101  118  135  137
170  187  204  221   13   30   32   49   66   83  100  117  134  136  153
186  203  220   12   29   31   48   65   82   99  116  133  150  152  169
202  219   11   28   45   47   64   81   98  115  132  149  151  168  185
218   10   27   44   46   63   80   97  114  131  148  165  167  184  201
  9   26   43   60   62   79   96  113  130  147  164  166  183  200  217
 25   42   59   61   78   95  112  129  146  163  180  182  199  216    8
 41   58   75   77   94  111  128  145  162  179  181  198  215    7   24
 57   74   76   93  110  127  144  161  178  195  197  214    6   23   40
 73   90   92  109  126  143  160  177  194  196  213    5   22   39   56
 89   91  108  125  142  159  176  193  210  212    4   21   38   55   72
105  107  124  141  158  175  192  209  211    3   20   37   54   71   88
106  123  140  157  174  191  208  225    2   19   36   53   70   87  104
```

Comment: is there a way to dump the arrays without the "columns" formatting but in  `format long e` accuracy?

Comment: @endolith: The NUM2STR function takes additional formatting arguments for that. Check the link I gave above for more details.